# calculate the where part in function SQL

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to calculate a bit "complicated" calcultation in SQL. I am programming with Python and using sqlite3.

I need to get the first record (called s say) which its lat and lng fields are between 2 values.
something like:

s.lat <= LAT <= s.lat+alpha and s.lng <= LNG <= s.lng+beta

I've tried to write this: 
lt,lg, alpha and beta are float variables

```
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM squares WHERE (lat <= ? and ? <= lat     + ? and long <= ? and ? <= long + ? ',(lt,lt,alpha,lg,lg,beta))
        rslt =c.fetchone()
        print rslt
```

bit it raises an exception

Thank you very much,

Sarah

Comment: you forgot to close the parenthesis opened after `WHERE`. When you ask a question saying your code raises an exception ALWAYS post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Duncan correctly pointed out about the parenthesis. Also,I would use the "BETWEEN" command instead of your line:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM squares WHERE (lat BETWEEN ? AND ?+? AND long BETWEEN ? AND ?+?'),(lt,lt,alpha,lg,lg,beta))
```